# Using regular expression with find&replace in vim

Tags: find, regular-expression, vim, directory, replace

I am wondering how to use regular expression to specify directories to be found and replaced inside vim.

For example: Changing the default DocumentRoot and Directory in httpd.conf.

Normally I use the following command to find and replace individual strings in vim, but this does not work for directories

```
:%s/tobefound/tobereplaced/g
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that you had:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

And you wanted to change `/var/www/html` to `/home/web`, you could do:

`:%s,/var/www/html,/home/web,g`

There's nothing "special" about `/`, it's just a common field delimiter.  You can use other characters; in my example I used `,`

Comment: This works best for my needs. Appreciate it Andy.

Comment: The perfect answer, no escaping and no extra chars to write. I discovered it recently and had a big laugh doing it for so long so complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Any `/` characters in both `tobefound` and `tobereplaced` will need to be escaped to `\/`, otherwise it will be interpreted as part of the syntax of the find and replace command.

E.g. replacing `/tmp/abc/` with `/srv/def/` would require `%s/\/tmp\/abc\//\/srv\/def\//g`

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to comment, I tried this and it works well